# Comparing and interlacing variables for editing purposes with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of names (staff in stafflist) from which I select some names and add them as an object to an array (paxlist). This operation is repeated, so several objects with different names are added into the array.

What I am attempting to do is to be able to edit each one of this objects to add or remove names.

For UX reasons, when I first select names from `stafflist`, they turn blue, and they reset to white when the object is added.

Basically, the effect/functionality I'm looking for is:

1. The object is added -> The main list resets
2. The edit button from one of the objects is clicked
3. The list of names of the object is compared with the main list, and the relevant names are highlighted (in blue) as existing/already selected names.
4. The user selects or deselects names.
5. The edition is completed, the resulting object saved and the main list reset.

I have a **[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KuGqQYNoZ2hxq2pIGwaU?p=preview)** depicting the addition functionality, but I don't see clear how could I compare and make the 2 variables (stafflist and pax in recordlist) work together as to edit the result.

I'm not specially looking for somebody to do it and solve this for me, but more to understand the logic behind a possible solution, as so far I can't think of anything...

Any comments will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/fzocQmZZoz9KHNXr6ytf?p=preview) with what I think you were trying to accomplish. Basically I just added a new state (editMode) which captured the pax being edited.

```
var editMode;

$scope.editRecord = function(record) {
  editMode = record.pax;
  $scope.stafflist.forEach(function (s) {
      s.chosen = false;
  });      

  record.pax.forEach(function(p) {
    $scope.stafflist.forEach(function (s) {
      if(p.name === s.name) {
        s.chosen = true;
      }
    });
  });
};
```

I then used this new state to figure out whether I was creating a new record or editing an existing one.

```
$scope.pushStaff = function (staff) {
    staff.chosen = true;
    var arr = editMode || $scope.paxlist;
    arr.push(staff);
};

$scope.unpushStaff = function (staff) {
    staff.chosen = false;
    var arr = editMode || $scope.paxlist;
    var index=arr.indexOf(staff);
    arr.splice(index,1);     
};
```

I'm sure there are cleaner approaches, but this is one way to do it.